# Nested class using declaration and access modifiers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, nested-class, access-modifiers, compiler-bug

while compiling some code that I ran into a compiler error that seemed strange to me and relates to inheritance, nested classes, using declarations, and access modifiers.

Basically, the intention is for a derived type to expose a nested protected class of a base type.

The the following short example to demonstrate the issue:

```
class Base
{
protected:

    struct Nested
    {
        enum value_enum
        {
            val = 0,
            val2,
            val3
        };
    };

};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:

    using Base::Nested;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Base::Nested aa; // error, as (I) expected
    //Base::Nested::value_enum ab; // error, as (I) expected

    Derived::Nested ba; // works, as (I) expected
    Derived::Nested::value_enum bb; // MSVC error, as (I) did not expect


    return 0;
}
```

See [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7344e2e25dbe32a0).

MSVC11 (v11.00.61030) chokes on this code with the following error:

> error C2248: 'Base::Nested' : cannot access protected struct declared in class 'Base'

Both GCC and Clang compile this properly, so without the ability to quote the relevant parts from the standard, I would argue this is an MSVC bug.

Is there a way around this with MSVC?

Comment: I think getting an error at compile time is better than running in to problems latter.

Comment: Since its protected, by standard main function will not be able to access it

Comment: @AliKazmi What is protected? `Derived` changes the access modifier for `Nested`; it is not protected in this case. Also, `value_enum` is not protected inside `Nested`.

Comment: Try  `typedef Base::Nested::value_enum value_enum;` in `Derived` class.

Comment: @Hrant MSVC does not complain about a `typedef Base::Nested Nested` (There are other types, etc; since is was only an SSCCE). I "like" that idea as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

For MSVC the following workaround works:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    public:

    using Base::Nested;
    typedef Base::Nested::value_enum value_enum; // add this
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Base::Nested aa; // error, as (I) expected
    //Base::Nested::value_enum ab; // error, as (I) expected

    Derived::Nested ba; // works, as (I) expected
    Derived::value_enum bb = Derived::value_enum::val; // now works in MSVC


    return 0;
}
```